# NSTableViewCell with different color and icons

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview

How to make a NSTableViewCell with different color and icons in different row,just looks like Applications in the finder? (icon and text are in the same column)

[image: finder]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `NSTableView`, call `setUsesAlternatingRowBackgroundColors:YES`.

Comment: You can also do this in Interface Builder. Just make sure that "Alternating Rows" is selected in the "Highlight" section of the attributes inspector for the table view.